# Range with repeated consecutive numbers

Tags: python, list, range, sequence, python-itertools

I would like to create a range (e.g. (1, 5)) of numbers with some repetitions (e.g. 4):

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

One way would be to write:

```
list(itertools.chain(*([x] * 4 for x in range(1, 5))))
```

Or similarly:

```
list(itertools.chain(*(itertools.repeat(x, 4) for x in range(1, 5))))
```

However, there is a flatting step, which could be avoided.

Is there a more pythonic or more compact version to generate such a sequence?

Comment: if you don't consider order, you could try this, `print  range(1,5)*4`. Or try this, `sorted(range(1,5)*4)`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, thanks for your input - unfortunately, order is relevant in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use a *list comprehension* instead.

```
l = [i for i in range(1, 5) for _ in range(4)]
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 8):

Nothing wrong with your solution. But you can use `chain.from_iterable` to avoid the unpacking step.

Otherwise, my only other recommendation is NumPy, if you are happy to use a 3rd party library.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
import numpy as np

# list solution
res = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 4) for i in range(1, 5)))

# NumPy solution
arr = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 5), 4)
```

Comment: @jpp- Nice answer with numpy based solution.

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
range(1,5)*4 # if you don't consider order
sorted(range(1,5)*4) # for ordered seq
```

**With performance updated**.

Mihai Alexandru-Ionut Answer:

```
%timeit [i for i in range(1, 5) for _ in range(4)]

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 µs per loop
```

jpp answer:

```
%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 4) for i in range(1, 5)))

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.12 µs per loop

%timeit np.repeat(np.arange(1, 5), 4)

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 µs per loop
```

Rory Daulton answer:

```
%timeit [n for n in range(1,5) for repeat in range(4)]

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 µs per loop
```

jedwards answer:

```
%timeit list(i//4 for i in range(1*4, 5*4))

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.47 µs per loop
```

RoadRunner Suggested in comment section:

```
%timeit for i in range(1, 5): lst.extend([i] * 4)

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 µs per loop
```

My answer:

```
%timeit sorted(range(1,5)*4)

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: With Python 3, this would be: `sorted(list(range(1, 5)) * 4)`. Anyway, nice hack - haven't though about that one.

Comment: @miku but doesn't sorting add unnecessary time complexity?

Comment: On top of flattening, you've added an `n log(n)` sort.

Comment: From the solutions been proposed I think this is the fastest

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yes, it would.

Comment: but most of the other answers seems to be O(n^2). Am I right?

Comment: To be fair @jpp answer using `numpy` is the fastest for long arrays. Using pure `python` this answer is the best for both this example and long arrays

Comment: Also this solution needs a `list()` call around the range object for Python 3 compatability

Comment: @miku - check the result with comparison.

Comment: Right but it stills fails in Python 3

Comment: @Mohamed You should measure performance with very large ranges and repetitions, where sort complexity matters. With a 16-element output, one could argue that simply returning the output is most efficient.

Comment: @user1093967 - I didn't argue with anyone. I just want to know the performance in detail. My code uses O(n log n), other code uses O(m*n). How my code performance is low?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Your solution requires the same time `O(mn)` time complexity for generating the unsorted list. See [time complexity for list multiplication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#line-24).

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Let's simply scale `m` and `n` tenfold to illustrate the difference in performance:

1. Your answer: `python -m timeit -n 1000000 'sorted(range(1,50)*40)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 264 usec per loop`

2. With `chain.from_iterable`: `python -m timeit -n 1000000 -s 'from itertools import chain, repeat' 'list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 40) for i in range(1, 50)))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 39.7 usec per loop`

3. Accepted answer, for comparison: `python -m timeit -n 1000000 '[i for i in range(1, 50) for _ in range(40)]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 75.7 usec per loop`

Comment: @user1093967- Thank you for your valuable comments. Next time I'll try to improve efficiency. Once again Thanks for teaching me this point.

Answer (score 3):

I think `chain` + `repeat` is likely your best bet.  That being said,

```
start = 1
stop = 5
repeat = 4

x = list(i//repeat for i in range(start*repeat, stop*repeat))

print(x)
```

Should work (for positive args, at least).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of code being simple and easy to understand. With that philosophy, I would use

```
[n for n in range(1,5) for repeat in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to mention, that `extend` might be an option too. Maybe not as beautiful as a one liner list comprehension, but it will perform better when the size of the `buckets` increase

```
def listExtend():
    a = []
    for i in range(1,5):
        a.extend([i]*4)
    return a


def listComprehension():
    return [[i,x] for i in range(1, 5) for x in range(4)]


import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="listComprehension()", setup="from __main__ import listComprehension", number=10**7))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="listExtend()", setup="from __main__ import listExtend", number=10**7))
14.2532608
8.78004566
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, although it requires installing a package, would be [`itertation_utilities.replicate`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/replicate.html):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import replicate
>>> list(replicate(range(1, 5), 4))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

In case you don't want to install that package the `replicate` function is essentially equivalent to this function:

```
from itertools import repeat

def replicate(items, repeats):
    for item in items:
        for _ in repeat(None, repeats):
            yield item
```

Just in case you're interested in the performance I did some micro-benchmarks for several (not all) of the proposed alternatives:

[image]

As you can see the NumPy and `iteration_utilities` approaches were 
fastest, while all the other approaches were roughly equally fast.

It's kind of interesting to note that of these other approaches the `list.extend` approach was fastest and (my) custom generator slowest. I didn't expect that.

And here is the code to replicate the benchmark:

```
from iteration_utilities import replicate
from itertools import chain, repeat
import numpy as np

def replicate_generator_impl(upper):
    for item in range(1, upper):
        for _ in repeat(None, 4):
            yield item

def replicate_generator(upper):
    return list(replicate_generator_impl(upper))

def iteration_utilities_replicate(upper):
    return list(replicate(range(1, upper), 4))

def double_comprehension(upper):
    return [i for i in range(1, upper) for _ in range(4)]

def itertools_chain(upper):
    return list(chain(*([x] * 4 for x in range(1, upper))))

def itertools_chain_from_iterable(upper):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 4) for i in range(1, upper)))

def extend(upper):
    a = []
    for i in range(1, upper):
        a.extend([i] * 4)
    return a

def numpy_repeat(upper):
    return np.repeat(np.arange(1, upper), 4)

from simple_benchmark import benchmark

funcs = [replicate_generator, iteration_utilities_replicate, double_comprehension, itertools_chain, itertools_chain_from_iterable, extend, numpy_repeat]
arguments = {2**i: 2**i for i in range(1, 15)}
b = benchmark(funcs, arguments, argument_name='size')
b.plot()
```

In case you were wondering how it would look like without the NumPy approach:

[image]

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [`iteration_utilities`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities) and [`simple_benchmark`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark).